# Interpolating a spline within dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, spline

I am trying interpolate splines for the following example data:

```
trt    depth    root    carbon
A       2        1        14
A       4        2        18
A       6        3        18
A       8        3        17
A      10        1        12
B       2        3        16
B       4        4        18
B       6        4        17
B       8        2        15
B      10        1        12
```

in the following way:

```
new_df<-df%>%
  group_by(trt)%>%
  summarise_each(funs(splinefun(., x=depth, method="natural")))
```

I get an `Error: not a vector`, but I don't see why not.  Am I not expressing the function in the right way?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I think something may not be right with the line `summarise_each(funs(splinefun(., x=depth, method="natural")))`.  Shouldn't it be something like `summarise_each(funs(splinefun(y = ., x=depth, method="natural")))` ?

Comment: `funs` is supposed to take a vector of function names or a list returned by `funs`.. I would not have expected `y=.` to work anyway, since y should be a vector and the value of `.` would be a table_df (or whatever those dplyr thingies are called. Can't offer a tested solution since all the efforts I made were segfaulting my current version of R with a current (on CRAN anyway) version of dplyr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want a dataset that contains the values interpolated?  If so, I've expanded the dataset to contain the desired *x* locations before the splines are calculated.

The resolution of those points are determined in the second line of the `expand.grid()` function. Just make sure the original depth points are a subset of the expanded depth points (eg, don't use something uneven like `by=.732`).

```
library(magrittr)
ds <- readr::read_csv("trt,depth,root,carbon\nA,2,1,14\nA,4,2,18\nA,6,3,18\nA,8,3,17\nA,10,1,12\nB,2,3,16\nB,4,4,18\nB,6,4,17\nB,8,2,15\nB,10,1,12")

ds_depths_possible <- expand.grid(
  depth            = seq(from=min(ds$depth), max(ds$depth), by=.5), #Decide resolution here.
  trt              = c("A", "B"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

ds_intpolated <- ds %>% 
  dplyr::right_join(ds_depths_possible, by=c("trt", "depth")) %>% #Incorporate locations to interpolate
  dplyr::group_by(trt) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    root_interpolated     = spline(x=depth, y=root  , xout=depth)$y,
    carbon_interpolated   = spline(x=depth, y=carbon, xout=depth)$y
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
ds_intpolated
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [34 x 6]

     trt depth  root carbon root_interpolated carbon_interpolated
   (chr) (dbl) (int)  (int)             (dbl)               (dbl)
1      A   2.0     1     14          1.000000            14.00000
2      A   2.5    NA     NA          1.195312            15.57031
3      A   3.0    NA     NA          1.437500            16.72917
4      A   3.5    NA     NA          1.710938            17.52344
5      A   4.0     2     18          2.000000            18.00000
6      A   4.5    NA     NA          2.289062            18.21094
7      A   5.0    NA     NA          2.562500            18.22917
8      A   5.5    NA     NA          2.804688            18.13281
9      A   6.0     3     18          3.000000            18.00000
10     A   6.5    NA     NA          3.132812            17.88281
..   ...   ...   ...    ...               ...                 ...
```

[image: root]
[image: carbon]

In the graphs above, the little points & lines are interpolated.  The big fat points are observed.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ds_intpolated, aes(x=depth, y=root_interpolated, color=trt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(shape=1) +
  geom_point(aes(y=root), size=5, alpha=.3, na.rm=T) +
  theme_bw()

ggplot(ds_intpolated, aes(x=depth, y=carbon_interpolated, color=trt)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(shape=1) +
  geom_point(aes(y=carbon), size=5, alpha=.3, na.rm=T) +
  theme_bw()
```

If you want an additional example, here's some recent [code](https://github.com/wibeasley/RAnalysisSkeleton/blob/master/manipulation/te-ellis.R) and [slides](https://rawgit.com/wibeasley/RAnalysisSkeleton/master/documentation/time-and-effort-synthesis.html).  We needed a rolling median for some missing points, and linear `stats::approx()` for some others.  Another option is also `stats::loess()`, but it's arguments aren't as similar as `approx()` and `spline()`.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to get `dplyr::summarise_each` (and also tried dplyr::summarise, since your choice of functions didn't seem to match you desire for multiple column input to return only two functions.) I'm not sure it's possible in `dply`. Here's what might be called the canonical method of approaching this:

```
 lapply( split(df, df$trt), function(d) splinefun(x=d$depth, y=d$carbon) )
#-------------

$A
function (x, deriv = 0L) 
{
    deriv <- as.integer(deriv)
    if (deriv < 0L || deriv > 3L) 
        stop("'deriv' must be between 0 and 3")
    if (deriv > 0L) {
        z0 <- double(z$n)
        z[c("y", "b", "c")] <- switch(deriv, list(y = z$b, b = 2 * 
            z$c, c = 3 * z$d), list(y = 2 * z$c, b = 6 * z$d, 
            c = z0), list(y = 6 * z$d, b = z0, c = z0))
        z[["d"]] <- z0
    }
    res <- .splinefun(x, z)
    if (deriv > 0 && z$method == 2 && any(ind <- x <= z$x[1L])) 
        res[ind] <- ifelse(deriv == 1, z$y[1L], 0)
    res
}
<bytecode: 0x7fe56e4853f8>
<environment: 0x7fe56efd3d80>

$B
function (x, deriv = 0L) 
{
    deriv <- as.integer(deriv)
    if (deriv < 0L || deriv > 3L) 
        stop("'deriv' must be between 0 and 3")
    if (deriv > 0L) {
        z0 <- double(z$n)
        z[c("y", "b", "c")] <- switch(deriv, list(y = z$b, b = 2 * 
            z$c, c = 3 * z$d), list(y = 2 * z$c, b = 6 * z$d, 
            c = z0), list(y = 6 * z$d, b = z0, c = z0))
        z[["d"]] <- z0
    }
    res <- .splinefun(x, z)
    if (deriv > 0 && z$method == 2 && any(ind <- x <= z$x[1L])) 
        res[ind] <- ifelse(deriv == 1, z$y[1L], 0)
    res
}
<bytecode: 0x7fe56e4853f8>
<environment: 0x7fe56efc4db8>
```